# Add ScrollBar to viewcontroller IOS 7 (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, uiscrollview, xcode6

I have a view controller that contains various controls in swift, when it turns to landscape, it doesn't show all controls, how can i put a scrollbar please?

Answer (score 0):

Add a UIScrollView to your UIViewController's view. Then add all of your subviews inside this UIScrollView. Adjust your scrollView's property accordingly when the device changes orientation.